# Limit to show Records with Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I would like show view more link if the item count is more than 5.The page should only display 5 records and view more link.The link should call the viewMore function

```
   <div>
      <span v-for="item in Items" v-bind:key="item.id">
            {{ item.label }}
      </span>
    </div>

export default {
  data() {
   return {
    items: []
  };
 },

  methods: {
    viewMore(id) {
      this.$router.push({ name:'item', parameter: {id}});
   },
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this: `<a @click="viewMore(item.id) v-show="items>5">View More</a>`.

Comment: What do you want exactly?

Comment: Thanks for you answer.I have modified the question.The page should only display 5 records and view more icon.Unfortunately its not working

Comment: Are you cosuming an API?

Comment: Its displaying all the records and not displaying view more with this condition v-show="items>5">View More</a>.

Comment: This was just to show the link when items are greater than 5.

Comment: Why don't you do pagination?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212108/discussion-between-azafo-cossa-and-user2410266).

Comment: That's what exactly i want.show the link when its greater than 5.Its a small section where pagination is not necessary.But for some reason its not working